# Firebase Missing App configuration value: "projectId" (installations/missing-app-config-values) in ReactJs using travis

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, travis-ci

firebase react app deployment works fine when deployed using the command line. However, I am getting the following error when deployed using Travis.
[image]

Below are my configuration files.

## .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
   - 12.1.0
warnings_are_errors: false
install:
  - npm install
script:
  - npm run build
deploy:
   provider: firebase
   skip_cleanup: true
   true:
      branch: main
token:
    secure: ****************************
```

env:
global:
secure: *****************************

## firebase.json

```
{
"hosting": {
    "site": "********",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## .env

```
API_KEY=''
AUTH_DOMAIN=''
PROJECT_ID=''
FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=''
FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=''
FIREBASE_APP_ID=''
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=''

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: 
  process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.measurementId
};

  firebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Comment: Have you set `projectId` in your "firebase.initializeApp({..." section? Could you share this section with demo data?

Comment: @SajibKhan Yeah... I am using .env file and initialize firebaseApp.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, with the exact same configuration. I was able to resolve  doing two things by wrapping the `env` vars within a *string* constructor - though not required its a good habit. Secondly, as I understand it latest `react` requires that `env` variable require the `REACT_APP` prefix to each variable.

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: String(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY),
  authDomain: String(process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN),
  projectId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID),
  storageBucket: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
messagingSenderId:String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID),
  measurementId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID),
};
```

Working Theory: when passing the env vars its recognizing the values as an object instead of a string value.

Hope that helps anyone looking for answers.